# XSLXWriter Insert multiple images at center of cell in a column

Tags: c++, qt, xlsx, libxlsxwriter

I am trying to use libxlsxwriter to insert images in a column row by row but the images are out of cell bound and on top of each other.

**Edit:**

I found that this line of code might be causing some issues `worksheet_set_default_row(worksheet,110,true);`

and changed my code to the following:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "QProcess"
#include "QThread"
#include "xlsxwriter.h"
#include <QtGui/QImage>
#include <QBuffer>
#include<QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QImage* img = new QImage("F:/Muaz/Programming/Visual C++/Qt/web_browser_open_close/Image0004.jpg");

    int pixel_width = int(25 * 7 + 0.5) + 5;
    int pixel_height = int(4.0 / 3.0 * 110);

    QImage scaled_img =img->scaled(pixel_width,pixel_height,Qt::KeepAspectRatio);

    int new_h = scaled_img.height();
    int new_w = scaled_img.width();

    QByteArray sbytes;
    QBuffer buffer(&sbytes);
    buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    scaled_img.save(&buffer, "jpg");
    buffer.close();

    unsigned char* data =new unsigned char[sbytes.size()];
    memcpy(data,sbytes.constData(),sbytes.size());

    QImage* img1 = new QImage("F:/Muaz/Programming/Visual C++/Qt/web_browser_open_close/Image0003.jpg");

    QImage scaled_img1 =img1->scaled(pixel_width,pixel_height,Qt::KeepAspectRatio);

    qInfo() << "width: " << new_w << ", height: " << new_h;
    qInfo() << "width: " << scaled_img1.width() << ", height: " << scaled_img1.height();

    QByteArray sbytes1;
    QBuffer buffer1(&sbytes1);
    buffer1.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    scaled_img1.save(&buffer1, "jpg");
    buffer1.close();

    unsigned char* data1 =new unsigned char[sbytes1.size()];
    memcpy(data1,sbytes1.constData(),sbytes1.size());

    qInfo() << sbytes.size();
    qInfo() << sbytes1.size();

    lxw_workbook  *workbook  = workbook_new("F:/Muaz/Programming/Visual C++/Qt/web_browser_open_close/sample.xlsx");
    lxw_worksheet *worksheet = workbook_add_worksheet(workbook, "Shop Items");

    worksheet_set_row(worksheet,0,110,NULL);
    worksheet_set_row(worksheet,1,110,NULL);
    worksheet_set_row(worksheet,2,110,NULL);
    worksheet_set_row(worksheet,3,110,NULL);
    worksheet_set_column(worksheet,1,1,25,NULL);

    lxw_image_options lio = {.x_offset =  (pixel_width-new_w)/2, .y_offset = (pixel_height-new_h)/2};

    worksheet_write_string(worksheet, 0, 0, "Ürün Adı", NULL);

    worksheet_insert_image_buffer_opt(worksheet,0,1,data,sbytes.size(), &lio);

    worksheet_write_string(worksheet, 1, 0, "Ürün Adı", NULL);

    lio = {.x_offset =  (pixel_width-scaled_img1.width())/2, .y_offset = (pixel_height-scaled_img1.height())/2};

    worksheet_insert_image_buffer_opt(worksheet,1,1,data1,sbytes1.size(), &lio);

    worksheet_write_string(worksheet, 2, 0, "Ürün Adı", NULL);

    workbook_close(workbook);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Now I get the following output:

[image]

The first image appears so small while the second one is slightly below the border line. Why is this?

How to insert the image at the center of the cell and within bounds of the cell width and height? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You  have to set the dpi to 96 (default for excel and other MS products) so that it is displayed correctly in the position at the correct size.

as QImage does have only set dot per meter i converted inch to meter then set dpm as follows:

```
QImage img

img.setDotsPerMeterX(3780);
img.setDotsPerMeterY(3780);
```

Now every thing is working as it should.